# 'int' object is not iterable after input function

Tags: python

I'm trying to change in input number into binary codes

```
number = int(input("input num : "))

for num in number:
    print(bin(num).split("b")[1])
```

However, I'm getting

```
      1 number = int(input("input num : "))
      2 
----> 3 for num in number:
      4     num2 = bin(num).split("b")[1]
`TypeError:'int' object is not iterable`
```

Can anyone help me out where I got wrong?

Much appreciation in advance

Comment: Well, an integer isn't iterable. A string is

Comment: You want to convert given number into binary or want to do someting else?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over *characters* of a string, not *digits* of a number.

```
number = input("input num : ")

for num in number:
    print(bin(int(num)).split("b")[1])
```